# RXJS snippet giving : 'this._next is not a function' when creating and invoking an Observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs

```
const myObservable = new rxjs.Observable(

   function(observer1){

        let button = document.getElementById('mybutton');
        //alert(observer1.error);

        button.addEventListener("click",observer1.next);
        alert(button);
        ///observer1.next(1);
    }
);

const myObserver = {
  next: x => console.log('Observer got a next value: ' + x),
  error: err => console.error('Observer got an error: ' + err),
  complete: () => console.log('Observer got a complete notification'),
};
myObservable.subscribe(myObserver);
```

the idea is that on evry click, the observer should be invoked. Why am I getting 'not a function ' error when button is clicked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const myObservable = new rxjs.Observable(

function(observer1){
alert('invoked');

let button = document.getElementById('mybutton');
var clickHandler = (arg) => observer1.next(arg);
button.addEventListener("click",clickHandler);
//alert("event listener added and myFun invoked");
//observer1.next(1);
}


);
const myObserver = {
  next: x => console.log('Observer got a next value: ' + x),
  error: err => console.error('Observer got an error: ' + err),
  complete: () => console.log('Observer got a complete notification'),
};
myObservable.subscribe(myObserver);
alert("ran it");
```

The idea is to wrap the observer1.next call inside a function as it needs to be called with the object context.

Answer (score 0):

According to this example it should be three parameters but not 1 object with 3 properties.

```
  var observer = Rx.Observer.create(
      x => console.log(`onNext: ${x}`),
      e => console.log(`onError: ${e}`),
      () => console.log('onCompleted'));

    observer.onCompleted();
```

there is your adjusted code

```
 let button = document.getElementById('mybutton');
 const myObservable= Rx.Observable.fromEvent(button , 'click')   

    myObservable.subscribe(
         x => console.log('Observer got a next value: ' + x),
         err => console.error('Observer got an error: ' + err),
         () => console.log('Observer got a complete notification')
    );
```

there is example from http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribe.html

```
var observer = Rx.Observer.create(
  function (x) { console.log('Next: %s', x); },
  function (err) { console.log('Error: %s', err); },
  function () { console.log('Completed'); });

var source = Rx.Observable.range(0, 3)

var subscription = source.subscribe(observer);
```

As you could see there are three parameters to static Rx.Observer.create method too.

https://jsfiddle.net/dhkoaufr/1/

Comment: dont know what you mean... can you make the above snippet working.

Comment: According to my reading of the docs (I don't know rxjs) what the OP has is fine [Subscribe operator may accept one to three methods.... **or** it may accept an object that implements the interface](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribe.html)

Comment: I guess you meant this code from your link (added to post).

Comment: @OlegBondarenko this version is also not working. can you please create a fiddle if you think otherwise?

Comment: it is odd when code from documentation is not working I have added worked example to jsfiddle